# Navigation between shared code project and cross platform application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, cross-platform, xamarin.uwp

I am working on a cross-platform application, I have already code for my universal windows platform application in the universal windows platform project and rest of the development I want to perform in the shared code. The case is I want to start my application(Solution) from the universal windows platform project and then on some button click, it will navigate to shared code project of the solution. So is there any way to navigate from the universal windows platform, project to the shared code project in the same solution???

Answer (score 0):

You can use MessagingCenter to trigger shared code when clicking the native button. You need to subscribe a message on shared project and send it after clicking the button on native project. You can find details in here:

[Messaging Center Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center)